# perl Net::Telnet hit enter if remote node ask for

Tags: perl

I had requirement to send command to remote device and whenever it ask for "Press CTRL+C to break, other key to continue..." I should again send "Enter key" to remote device.

I have written below scritpt but somehow it doesn't work.

```
my $session = new Net::Telnet (
    Timeout => 30, 
    Prompt=> '/>/', 
    Input_log  =>\*STDOUT
);
$session->open('device-id');
$session->login('admin','admin');

print "connected and logged in \n\n"; 
print "Kindly wait till output stored in FILE \n\n";

my @output1=$session->cmd('DSP PATCH:;');
if ($session->waitfor('/Press CTRL+C to break, other key to continue.../')) {
    $session->print('');   # Assuming default is \n for print command
}

print @output1;
```

Output of above script is

---

```
connected and logged in

Kindly wait till output stored in FILE

.

.

some output of command send...........

.
Press CTRL+C to break, other key to continue...
```

---

and then it timeout.

Any idea how to send enter hit till my remote device ask me to hit enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cmd` method sends a command and waits for the prompt. Instead, either run your command using `print` and `waitfor` (most likely saving the returned prematch), or override the prompt for that `cmd` call with the remote message. I'd suggest doing the former.

Comment: Thanks hasturkun, with your suggestion I managed to hit enter via. script....now problem is how to store all output to a file...it print output of after hitting enter...                                                          my @output=$session->print('DSP PATCH:;');
while ($session->waitfor('/continue/')) {
push (@output,$session->print());
push (@output,$session->waitfor('/continue/'));

}                      if someone help how to store everything which is contains in STDOUT my problem will be solved....

Comment: OK I got it via....Input_log  =>\*FILE1    it store all output to file handle:FILE1............Thanks a lot for your help...regards: Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Did you check using   `$session -> dumplog()`  for debugging purpose?

Try this ::  `my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new(Timeout => 30,Errmode => 'return');`

Taken from [Here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=538684)